# find a continuous range of rows with the same column values

Tags: sqlite

I have a table **e** with increase primary key. One of the example rows looks like this:

```
id | name | year | info
3  | a    | 1    | any
5  | a    | 1    | any
6  | a    | 1    | any
7  | b    | 3    | any
9  | b    | 3    | any
10 | a    | 3    | any
11 | a    | 1    | any
```

I want to get all those **continuous** rows start from minimum row has the same name & year value as the min row (id 3). <strike>The limit is I need to get the result using one single SELECT statement.</strike>

So in this example, the result should be 3,5,6:

```
3 | a | 1 | any
5 | a | 1 | any
6 | a | 1 | any
```

If we delete these three rows and query again, we should get 7, 9:

```
7 | b | 3 | any
9 | b | 3 | any
```

This is my current query but it does not work. I am new to SQL want to know how to simplify this?

```
SELECT * 
FROM e AS E1, 
     (SELECT name, year FROM e WHERE id = (SELECT min(id) FROM e)) AS M1 
WHERE 
     E1.name = M1.name AND 
     E1.year = M1.year AND 
     E1.id < (SELECT min(id) 
              FROM e AS E2 
              WHERE E2.name != M1.name OR E2.year != M1.year)
```

Comment: How can a single query have multiple result sets? What NULLs are you talking about?

Comment: Sorry for confusing, I mean one select statement, not actually query. And NULL cases is all rows has the same name and year, I query I wrote not work.

Comment: Can you post what output data you really expect for?

Comment: What's your logic to filter row with id 11 at first? Row with id 11 also has the same name and year as the row with id 3.

Comment: @JaugarChang The IDs are not continuous; there are other IDs between 6 and 11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM e
WHERE /* id > last_id_from_previous_result AND */
      id < COALESCE((SELECT min(e.id)
                     FROM e
                     JOIN (SELECT id, name, year
                           FROM e
                           /* WHERE id > last_id_from_previous_result */
                           ORDER BY id
                           LIMIT 1) AS first
                       ON /* e.id > first.id AND */
                          (e.name != first.name OR
                           e.year != first.year)),
                    'infinite')
```

The innermost query searches for the first ID to be returned.

The middle query searches for the first row that does not belong into the result, i.e., the first row with a larger ID that has a different `name` or `year`.
At the end of the table, the result of that is NULL; the COALESCE then returns a value that is larger than any number.

The outermost query then returns all rows before that row.

If you don't want to delete all previous rows, you can add the commented-out checks to continue after the last ID from the previous query. (At the beginning, use a value smaller than all your IDs, such as `-1`.)

Comment: Great work! FYI `e.id > first.id AND` could be removed.